# develop firefox extension which will disable incognito browsing

Tags: firefox, xml

I hope to design a browser extension for children where their parents can track their actions using cookies. The first step of that would be disable private browsing as inbuilt feature in the extension. I tried following code but it still private browsing can be done. Can anyone trace error 
 Given below my manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Cat Gifs!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "incognito":"not_allowed",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Cat Gifs!"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extensions cannot disable this feature.

The manifest parameter actually means the [*opposite*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito) – that the browser disables the *extension* whenever the user starts incognito mode.

Comment: @grawith oh really? isn't there anyway to do this?

Comment: I don't know, but I sure hope not.